# Expo cli update not happening

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to upgrade expo-cli from 2.11 to 2.18 but `npm i -g expo-cli@latest` still points to the old version.

when I typed `expo-cli -V` it resulted:

> **2.11**  ...so naturally npm i -g expo-cli@latest will grab the latest version and install it but still expo-cli -v is still pointing to the old version.

I remember installing packages in bash level is a no go operation.

these are some images to put it all into context:
[image]
[image]

Update: Removed Nodes modules as suggested in the first answer, and that lead to npm removal both expo and expo-cli are not found with the command `where` 
[image]

Answer (score 17):

For mac users (linux should be very similar):

Find your expo-cli version:

```
which expo-cli
```

For me it yielded:

```
/Users/username/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/expo-cli
```

Remove this outdated version:

```
rm -rf /Users/username/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/expo-cli
```

Check that you are using the latest version:

```
expo-cli --version
```

Answer (score 10):

Updating expo-cli globally can be a right pain. To those experiencing this frustration, use yarn

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

it will give you far fewer headaches

Comment: yarn global add expo-cli

Comment: This works because you let old versions of expo litter in your NPM directories and just installed into Yarn instead, ending up with more junk on your computer.

Comment: I just spent 30 minutes battling expo-cli with npm, and then felt nothing but joy as it was seamlessly installed in yarn

Comment: Same, couldn't fix it with nom, even following the "which expo-cli" suggestion. yarn solved it

Answer (score 6):

If you're like me, and none of this stuff worked, maybe my solution will help.
My problem is that I switched from NPM, to Yarn at some point, and I had global packages in both systems, which was giving me a bunch of trouble.

Step 1: Make sure you don't have expo-cli in global npm

`npm list-g`

Step 2: If it is in global npm, uninstall it

`npm uninstall --global expo-cli`

Step 3: Install it fresh with yarn

`yarn global add expo-cli`

Step 4: Stop using npm for global packages (or at least, only use one system)

edit: spelling

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac, these 2 commands will do the tricks
1)which expo to locate expo in your Mac which will give you this "/usr/local/bin/expo"
2) "cd /usr/local/bin/"
3)-rm expo 
4)-rm expo-cli

Comment: This above tip works because you're removing *both* expo and expo-cli. No need to `cd` into the directories, though. `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/expo`, `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/expo-cli`

Answer (score 1):

1. expo-cli --version
2. npm uninstall expo-cli
3. npm install -g expo-cli
4. expo-cli --version

if cannot, you can update manually

1. check path
   npm bin -g
2. change "node_modules" folder or remove
   C:\Users{username}.npm-global\node_modules
3. npm install -g expo-cli
4. copy\past expo-cli folder
   from C:\Users{username}.npm-global\node_modules\expo-cli
   to C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
5. expo-cli --version

Answer (score 1):

You can also move from the global expo cli to the [New Local expo cli](https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421)

You just need to run

```
npx expo start
```

In the root of the project and it will install it if it's not already there.

Answer (score 0):

the hole system was behaving oddly!, `npm` should've been installed with `node` but it was nowhere to be found.
I had to remove node and reinstall it again, then I had to install expo-cli again and all errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

When npm does not work in an easy way, `--force` it!

```
npm install -g expo-cli --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of Expo CLI:
npm i -g expo-cli. expo-cli@4.7.2 or greater is required.
Update to the latest version of EAS CLI if you use it:
npm i -g eas-cli.
Run expo upgrade in your project directory.

Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

there is more than a reason for not updating the expo-cli.

**reason 1** - you maybe installed expo-cli using yarn and after a while you need to update and using npm `npm install -g expo-cli` it will update but maybe when you run expo its point to that yarn version so to resolve this you need to run `yarn global remove expo-cli`.

**reason 2** - it might you have two versions of expo-cli one its global version and one inside your project folder/path, so even you upgrade expo-cli globally, your project still point to the first class version which is in your project folder. to resolve this you need to uninstall expo-cli which exists in your project folder to point to the global version and you can do this using this command `npm uninstall expo-cli` **notice** without `-g`.

**reson 3** - sometimes you need to clean npm cache. if nothing works for you above try to uninstall expo-cli using `npm uninstall -g expo-cli` and then run this command `npm cache clean --force` then install expo-cli again `npm install -g expo-cli`.